# How to get the replication ID from CDTReplicator object using swift?

Tags: swift, cloudant

I am using the Cloudant DB and in the CDTReplicatorDelegate when I print the description of the replicator object, I see that it has a unique replication session ID. How do I access this using the object?  There are no properties for it.

Sample output of `replicator.description`:

`CDTReplicator push, source: establishment, target: https://ighterequallockneovessin:*****@*****.cloudant.com/establishment filter name: (null), filter parameters (null), unique replication session ID: 930C1002-B0B2-4576-BE84-C0BEFBD00834`

I am storing the replicator objects (more than one) in a single delegate and when the replication is complete, I would like to remove its reference. This is why I need it.

```
func appendReplicator(replicator: CDTReplicator) {
        replicators.append(replicator)
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a single delegate for multiple replicators. I only have two replicators, so when a replicator starts I just store a reference to it in one of those two vars. When it completes I compare the replicator passed into the `replicatorDidComplete` function to those vars. Could you do something like this?

```
var replicators : [CDTReplicator] = []

// on start
replicators.append(replicator)

// on complete, error, etc
func replicatorDidComplete(replicator: CDTReplicator!) {
    var match: Int? = nil
    for (index,r) in replicators.enumerate() {
        if (r == replicator) {
            match = index
            break
        }
    }
    if (match != nil) {
        replicators.removeAtIndex(match!)
    }
```

I would move that into a `removeReplicator` function so you can call it from `replicatorDidComplete`, `replicatorDidError`, etc.

Comment: Just perfect! I used the identity operator `===` instead of the equality. But essentially the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't. Its an internal detail thats deliberately, the best thing to do is raise a feature request on [github](https://github.com/cloudant/CDTDatastore/) if you really want to be able to access the replicator session ID.

Comment: It's not a must but would have been neater in my case. Now I will use separate delegates to keep track.